# Filtering elements from a complex XML document

Tags: xml, scala, xslt, xml-parsing, sax

I have this XML - the objective is to filter certain properties from the XML given some conditions:
so, get the `SALARY` of a player whose `NAME` is **ALONSO** and `POSITION` is a **STRIKER**

```
<PLAYERS>
  <PLAYER>
    <NAME>ALONSO</NAME>
    <POSITION>MIDFIELDER</POSITION>
    <AGE>28</AGE>
    <NATIONALITY></NATIONALITY>
    <SALARY>550000</SALARY>
  </PLAYER>
  <PLAYER>
    <NAME>MANE</NAME>
    <POSITION>STRIKER</POSITION>
    <AGE>30</AGE>
    <NATIONALITY></NATIONALITY>
    <SALARY>600000</SALARY>
  </PLAYER>
  <PLAYER>
    <NAME>ALONSO</NAME>
    <POSITION>STRIKER</POSITION>
    <AGE>23</AGE>
    <NATIONALITY>SPAIN</NATIONALITY>
    <SALARY>250000</SALARY>
  </PLAYER>
</PLAYERS>
```

This is what I tried -

```
val salary = ("PLAYERS").flatMap {
      case pNode if (pNode \\ "PLAYER" \\ "NAME").head.text == "ALONSO" =>
        (pNode \\ "PLAYER" \\ "SALARY").headOption.map(_.text)
      case _ => None
    }.headOption
 
 // result   
 salary
```

This seems to return the first salary in the XML - which isn't what I require!
Any assistance will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question as `xslt`, here's an XSLT answer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/PLAYERS">
    <xsl:value-of select="PLAYER[NAME='ALONSO' and POSITION='STRIKER']/SALARY"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: was hoping for a scala related solution - thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

In the current code, you are checking whether the first node of an `Elem` contains `"ALONSO"`. So if you change the order and make the first player's name `"Rooney"`, for eg, you will get an empty list.

Instead, you could try,

```
players.child.flatMap {
  case pNode if (pNode \\ "PLAYER" \\ "NAME").text == "ALONSO" =>
    (pNode \\ "PLAYER" \\ "SALARY").headOption.map(_.text)
  case _ => None
}
```